# Is a Stored Procedure suitable for my task

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am completely new to SQL Server and a bit lost. When I try the following, it executes the first three lines and ignores the rest, just get

> 'Command(s) completed successfully.'

```
USE [RenewalsDb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[One] 

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DROP TABLE [dbo].NewTransTable;

SELECT * INTO [dbo].[NewTransTable] FROM [dbo].aqryTransTable;

DELETE FROM  [dbo].[NewTransTable] WHERE  (((NewTransTable.CURRENT_LICENSE_SKU_DESC) Like '% partner program %'));

DELETE FROM  [dbo].[NewTransTable] WHERE (((NewTransTable.RENEWAL_MAINTAINANCE_SKU_DESC) Like '% partner program %'));

UPDATE NewTransTable SET NewTransTable.[Quote Number] = Null;

UPDATE dbo.TransactionTable SET Concat = dbo.qryNamedAcReseller.LATEST_DISTRIBUTOR_NAME + dbo.qryNamedAcReseller.[Sub Territory FY14   ]
FROM  dbo.TransactionTable INNER JOIN
    dbo.qryNamedAcReseller ON dbo.TransactionTable.LATEST_INSTANCE_NUMBER = dbo.qryNamedAcReseller.LATEST_INSTANCE_NUMBER;

UPDATE dbo.TransactionTable SET Concat = dbo.qryNamedAcReseller.[Sub Territory FY14   ]
FROM  dbo.TransactionTable INNER JOIN
    dbo.qryNamedAcReseller ON dbo.TransactionTable.LATEST_INSTANCE_NUMBER = dbo.qryNamedAcReseller.LATEST_INSTANCE_NUMBER
WHERE Concat IS NULL;

UPDATE dbo.NewTransTable SET [Quote Number] =  dbo.Autogen.[Quote Number] FROM dbo.Autogen RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.NewTransTable ON dbo.Autogen.[IB Reference Num] = dbo.NewTransTable.LATEST_INSTANCE_NUMBER AND 
    dbo.Autogen.[Quote Known As] = dbo.NewTransTable.[Quote Known As]
DROP TABLE [dbo].NewTransTable2; 

SELECT * INTO [dbo].[NewTransTable2] FROM [dbo].aqryTransTable2;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].NewTransTable2 ADD Named_Account nvarchar(255);

END

GO
```

Comment: You aren't actually running any of the SQL code after the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement. All you are doing is creating a Stored Procedure. To actually run the Stored Procedure, from SSMS, you could use: `exec [dbo].[One]`

Comment: Also, the procedure will throw and error when you run it. Your first step is to `DROP` the `NewTransTable`, and then the next step is trying to insert into it, essentially you will be inserting into a table that no longer exists.

Comment: @mikeyq6 No it won't `SELECT * INTO` rebuilds the table based on the structure of the table in the `FROM`.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. My mistake

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

Stored Procedure is like a template which can reused multiple times and it can be made dynamic with the help or parameters. Refer [mssqltips.com - SQL Server Stored Procedure Tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure-tutorial/) on guide to Stored Procedures. If you want to execute some commands only once, Stored Procedure is not the right thing.

So when you execute the above script, what SQL Server is doing is creating the template structure i.e. Stored procedure named [One] and not actually running the scripts within the stored procedure.

To execute this stored procedure named [One] you have to call it using `EXEC One` or just simply `One` and Execute (F5)

Comment: Many thanks folks: I "blush" as how long I have been stuck on this one. It will be one of four similar procedures used to process data in a database I am transitioning from MS Access, so I will be using them repeatedly. Cheers again